# Can human created heating increase the temperature of the planet surface/atmosphere?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, planets

If we ignore the greenhouse effect and imagine all the worlds energy is produced by nuclear or other power plants would the energy needed by humanity to heat be enough to measurably increase the temperature of the whole atmosphere?

In my imagination heating for a few billion people around the world should increase the temperature of the atmosphere.

Comment: You are aware that all the energy available on earth comes ultimately from solar and nuclear (geothermal), right?  So, neglecting fossil fuels, whose source is solar, is naive.  And, of course, the energy humanity gives off can be traced back to solar.

Comment: Not sure I follow your explanation. By using nuclear energy we can convert nuclear energy to heat thereby increasing the temperature for that amount. I am asking can humanity produce enough heat to actually have an measurable impact on all the gases in our atmosphere. I will edit my question to include fossil fuels, I am not interested in the kind of fuel we would need to do it, just would it be possible without using the greenhouse effect.

Comment: You seem to be asking "if the atmosphere and humanity were considered an thermodynamically closed system and all the metabolic energy released by humans were released to the atmosphere, how fast would the atmosphere heat up?"  Is that it?

Answer (score 1):

Increase? Sure.  We can always increase it.  We can have a non-zero effect on heating by causing heating.

Increase by much?  Well.  One of my favorite tables on the internet is [Orders of Magnitude (Energy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(energy)) on Wikipedia:

> $3.9\cdot10^{22} \text J$    Estimated energy contained in the world's fossil fuel reserves as of 2010
>
> $5.5\cdot10^{24} \text J$    Total energy from the Sun that strikes the face of the Earth each year.

That's right.  Each year, over 100 times as much energy strikes the Earth from the sun as we have in the *entire* known fossil fuel reserves.  If we burned it all, in a year, we could increase the heating of the surface of the planet by just shy of 1%.  Then the next year we'd run out of fuels and it would go back down.

If we bring in nuclear power, we can do a little better

> $2.2\cdot10^{23} \text J$    Total global uranium-238 resources using fast reactor technology

So if we use *all* of the available uranium on the entire planet, we can increase the heating of the surface by something like 4% for one year.

And just for fun:

> $5\cdot10^{23} \text J$    Approximate energy released in the formation of the Chicxulub Crater in the Yucatán Peninsula

Even if we use our energy to set about a mass extinction event never seen in recorded history, we still won't do it with the raw bravado of a hunk of space rock with a death wish!